# Session value changes on postback in Citrix Xen App

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, citrix

We use a citrix reciever to view a application hosted in server.

The Application works fine when it is viewed normally (not through citrix).

The issue i have is, I have a dropdown in my master page. When i login the Session will be defaulted and dropdown assigned. When i change the dropdown item, the session gets changed and the dropdwon will show the correct value selected.

After this when i click on any links that cause postback, the Session value defaults to the default value and the dropdown shows the default value.

for eg:

When i login I default the Session("Budget") to "1" and the dropdown will show "Budget 1".
No i change the Dropdwon to "budget 2" and the session("budget") is now "2".

Now when i click any link which causes postback, the Session("budget") becomes "1" and dropdown defaults to "Budget 1".

Can anyone suggest what is the problem.. This happens only when i view the app in the Citrix desktop.

Regards
rajeesh